# $scope.push() does not update ng-repeat after http post success

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to update the DOM (ng-repeat) (calling an $http.get) on my view after an $http.post is successful, however it does not work.

I did test using ng-click calling my $http.get and it does update the DOM, so I'm confused what's going on.

this is my $http.post:

```
 $scope.save = function(){
    //url, data and config here...
    $http.post(url, data, configPost).then(function(data) {
    if(data.status == 200){

      if ($scope.formData.comment) {
        $scope.formData.comment = '';
        $scope.response.push(initget()); // this is where I'm calling the $http get
      }

    } else {
      console.log('post error');
    }
  });
};
```

I did a test using the following function and it works outside the $http.post:

```
$scope.updateDOM = function() {
    $scope.response.push(initget());
};

<a href="#" ng-click="updateDOM()">update dom</a>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you saying that initget() returns a promise?

Comment: yes, I'm using $http.get('/someUrl', config).then(successCallback, errorCallback); for my get method.

Comment: I'm not seeing an `ng-repeat` anywhere in the question... Please read how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get it correctly once you submit (post) some data you want to refresh the view with remaining data.
I think you can try:

```
$http.get('/someUrl', config).then(function(data){$scope.response = data;})
```

in your callback success of the POST call instead of pushing. i.e. instead of:

```
$scope.response.push(initget());
```

P.S. I am assuming you are applying ng-repeat on $scope.response.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was because "ng-controller" was defined twice in html template.